# How do I create a grouped bar chart inside of a for loop, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Backstory: I absolutely have to use matplotlib for this, sadly. I need to create a grouped bar chart. I do not know how many traces the chart will have, so i can not explicitly state the width for each. As of now, this is the relevant code;

```
fig = plt.figure()
...
...
...
            if np.mean(height) > 4000 and len(height) > 6:
                label = page.split(' (')[0].split(' ')
                label = ' '.join(label[-2:])
                ax1 = ax.bar(
                    x=[d for d in dates],
                    height=[v / 1000 for v in vals.values()],
                    label=label
                )
```

Attached is the plot
[make me grouped and not stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7J9l.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney attached the plot